# Convert java object to csv and upload to google cloud storage

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-storage

I have a rest endpoint which takes an object (requestbody) as input. I need to read that object, convert it to csv and upload the csv on google cloud storage.

I am sharing below, what I have been able to achieve so far:

```
@GetMapping("/upload")
public void getTranscriptsByDate(@RequestBody SearchRequest searchRequest) throws Exception{
    log.info("Search Request {}", searchRequest);

    createFileWithSerachCriteria(searchRequest);
    uploadFileToGoogleCloudStorage(searchRequest);

}

private void createFileWithSerachCriteria(SearchRequest searchRequest) throws IOException {
    String filename =  "myFile" + searchRequest.getConversationDate() + ".csv";
    String filePath = "C://Users//abc//" + filename;

    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(filePath));
    String[] header = { "ID", "NAME" };
    writer.writeNext(header);

    String[] data = new String[2];
    data[0] = searchRequest.getId();
    data[1] = searchRequest.getName();
    writer.writeNext(data);

    writer.close();
}

private void uploadFileToGoogleCloudStorage(SearchRequest searchRequest) throws Exception{
    tring filename =  "myFile" + searchRequest.getConversationDate() + ".csv";
    String filePath = "C://Users//abc//" + filename;
    myService.uploadFile(filePath);
}
```

Below is the code from MyService.java

```
public void uploadFile(String localFilePath) throws Exception{
    BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucketName, localFilePath);
    BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).build();
    storage.createFrom(blobInfo, Paths.get(localFilePath));
}
```

This code works fine.

I do not want to write a file on local and then read it back to upload to cloud. I want to directly convert my request object to csv and upload it on cloud without the 2 step (read/write) process. On official GCP documentation I found a small example of streaming, but I am unable to understand it.

Is it possible to achieve what I am thinking to do i.e. avoiding the read/write and doing it in one go. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use byte streams to both read and write the file data in-memory instead of the file system:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter streamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(stream);
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(streamWriter);

// add data to writer and close

BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucketName, someDerivedFilePath);
BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).build();
storage.createFrom(blobInfo, new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray()));
```

FYI, I haven't tested this but it looks like it should work.

Comment: Why would you write to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, when you can create an output stream to a blob, and write to that directly? There is no need to waste memory like this. And if this is a serious application, you might run into cases where the resulting file is far larger than available memory, and this would throw an `OutOfMemoryError` (either when writing, or when calling `stream.toByteArray()`, which creates a **copy** of the array held in the `ByteArrayOutputStream`).